# Adjust raster value if cell contains a point in ArcMap?

Tags: raster, arcmap

My raster consists of 100x100m cells that all have the value 0, and a shape with point data. I'd like to update all the cells that contain a point to 1, but can't seem to find a tool that does this. It is possible to do this using a tool (or multiple tools) from the toolbox?

What I mostly find when trying to look this up is 'point to raster', which I don't think is what I need, and I believe 'con' does not work with shapefiles.

I'd like to do it in ArcMap (10.4). I'm trying to avoid using a python script, as I'm having lots of trouble loading the arcpy module on my computer.

Comment: You already have the two tools you need, you just need to use them together (use Con with the output of  Point to Raster)